# public interface inf1 { void show(); } public interface inf2 { void show(); } public class A:inf1:inf2 { }

Tags: c#

```
public interface inf1 { void show(); } 

public interface inf2 { void show(); }

public class A:inf1:inf2 {

}
```

how to slove this please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface inf1 { void show(); } 

public interface inf2 { void show(); }

public class A:inf1,inf2 {
   public void inf1.show(){}
   public void inf2.show(){}
}
```

This is explicit implementation of interface.